# How to open a door without it creaking?

Tags: home, door, sound

The obvious answer is to oil it. But until then, is there any way to open it without the terrible creaking sound?

Once in a while it has opened quietly. I think putting pressure on certain parts of the door helps.

Comment: I'm quite lazy to oil the door in my bedroom and the following method works for me: while opening the door, pull it also slightly up (not sure this is good enough for the answer).

Comment: doors never creak when ninja's open them, ergo becoming a ninja will solve your problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The squeaking noise is often made by friction as the hinges rub. If that's the case, I will turn the doorknob and pull straight up, basically lifting the door so that it presses against the top of the hinges, which are less likely to squeak.

Comment: I read this question and thought _exactly_ what you said. Bravo!

Answer (score 4):

You should lubricate the hinge and doorknob mechanism with oil. GT-85 or other teflon-containing lubricants are the best. If you're not in a position to do that:

[WikiHow:](http://www.wikihow.com/Open-a-Door-Silently)

> Take light, slow steps as you are opening the door. That way, no one
>   will hear the squeak of the floorboards and/or tile as you enter the
>   room.
>
> Be careful when turning the doorknob because some doorknobs can be
>   very noisy as you turn and let go. If it is noisy, turn very slowly
>   and let go slowly, only releasing when it is back in its original
>   position.
>
> Turn the doorknob so that the least rotation is needed. If the hinges
>   are on the right, rotate the doorknob clockwise. If the hinges are on
>   the left, rotate the doorknob counterclockwise. This holds true
>   whether the door opens toward you or away from you.
>
> After you turn the doorknob, press the door upward and then toward the
>   hinges in rapid succession as you open the door. This will help to
>   reduce the noise the door makes as it separates from the jamb.

Jamming the door upward and toward the hinges immobilizes it and makes the chance of squeaking unlikely.

---

**Additional Info**

[Some people say spit on the hinges.](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100728000758AAOT0gB)

[Doors are sticky and noisy when opened?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/doors-are-sticky-and-noisy-when-opened) For obstructions near the door.

> sand down or strip the offending parts until they clear each other
>   without touching (and possibly repaint with a single coat if you need
>   to). I'd expect sanding only to "rough it up" to increase the
>   friction, not make it better.

[Hone Guides](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/make-doors-not-creak-49375.html)

Comment: I guess some doors are just too sticky to fully get rid of the squeak, but lifting did help.

Comment: WD-40 is *not* the right choice of oil! It is not a lubricant: WD stands for water displacement. You may want to spray some in initially, as it will penetrate and clean the hinge, but you're going to want to put proper lubricant in: GT-85 or Lithium Grease.

Comment: The two additional lubricants for doors are graphite - as in pencil lead - and soap - graphite is often used for lubricating locks while rubbing with soap will often stop a door sticking.

Comment: @TomMedley WD-40 works well if the hinge was oiled long time ago and the lubricant has "dried up" (I don't know how to better describe it).

Answer (score 1):

Often, lifting up the door and pushing toward the hinges keeps the hinges from squeaking.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lipsalve aka chapstick on the hinges, push it into the gaps between the two hinge leaves with your fingers. It also works on swinging shower screens. Oil runs out, lipsalve just stays put.

Answer (score -2):

Do the following:

- Muffle your footsteps
- Turn the knob
- If hinges are towards right then turn clockwise
- If hinges are towards left then turn counter clockwise
- Lift the door
- Turn against the knobs then boom and add water to lower the noise chance.

Comment: boom and add water? I've no idea what that means.